# Safari won't load pages after system restore

Tags: mac, safari, macos, time-machine, restore

I hope someone can advise please...

A few days ago I had to restore my whole system from Time Machine backup after a power outage stopped my Mac from booting up.  Everything seems fine, except for Safari.

Safari now won't load any web pages, it just shows a message at the top: "this webpage was reloaded because a problem occurred".  Other browsers are fine.

My MacOS is High Sierra 10.13.6

Safari version is 12.0.3

I have read other pages that suggest that maybe when I was restoring, that the newest version of Safari might have downloaded via "automatic updates" from the App store, but I don't know (a) what version of Safari I had before, and (b) whether Safari 12.0.3 is meant to be OK with High Sierra 10.13.6?

Any clues or advice welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This could be a problem with the wrong version of Safari, or it could be a problem with its cache or preference file.

Start by deleting the cache folder, located here:

```
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/
```

If that doesn't work, delete the preference file here:

```
/Users/sklein/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist
```

If the problem persists, delete Safari (by dragging it to the Trash), then reinstall macOS High Sierra from [Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904).

The reinstall will take a while, but you won't lose any apps or data.

Comment: Or you could just clear the cache "Clear history..." from the Safari menu and then (if needed) apply the latest combo update which usually updates Safari.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions so far.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions so far.

I have already tried clearing cache, but that didn't help.  I tried to go into Safari Preferences - but as soon as I click on the Preferences option Safari quits (I get a "Safari quit unexpectedly" box).

Sorry to sound dim but how do I get to the files "~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/" and "/Users/sklein/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist" ?

And again - this may be a dim question but how /where would I apply the "latest combo update" - do you mean from App store?

Thanks for any further advice (and for your patience with a newbie!)